# Fixing on Menu ON One Page Scroll Site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, parallax

I have a site in which i have to use Parallax scrolling. I used the bookmarking.js script from dynamicdrive.com . But when i click on the menu item it is working, but the top portion of each divison is going below the nav bar.

Here is the Site :- http://coalitionspace.microoffice.com/

Please take a look on the screen-shot here :-
[image]

And here is what i want this to be:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your are loggedin into wordpress, If so add the height of the wordpress menu bar to your position top. For example:

`<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

  echo '<style type="text/javascript">.nav.fixed { top: [height_of_admin_bar]px; </style>';

 } ?>`

Or you can hide the admin bar like:

`add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');`